# What is meaning of BEFORE and AFTER in this hook name?

Tags: hooks, s2member

I'm trying to interpret this action hook name:

```
ws_plugin__s2member_pro_before_sc_authnet_form_after_shortcode_atts
```

What is meaning of BEFORE and AFTER in this hook name? Do the underscores mean anything?

It seems that the hook name contains two function names, `sc_authnet_form` and  `shortcode_atts`, that are connected by BEFORE and AFTER words.

Answer (score 0):

The `ws_plugin__s2member_pro_before_sc_authnet_form_after_shortcode_atts`  hook is one hook and not a combination of hooks. This hook is probably from the s2member plugin from what I can determine from the hook name.

Frankly, I do not know the plugin, also, third party plugins are still considered off topic here, so I cannot give a specific answer, but in short, reading the extra loooonnngggg hook name, this hook is in between two actions/filters/functions/custom code. Most probably this will be **before** the `sc_authnet_form` hook/filter/function but **after** the `shortcode_atts` function.

Although the hook name is really long, it is very descriptive and gives you a very good idea where the hook is used. This is just very good coding practice. Function, class, variable, filter and action names should always be descriptive. It just makes your code easier to follow and gives one a good idea what a function etc should be doing

### EDIT

The underscores are basic PHP. Simply stated, all words in function/filter/action/variable names should be separated by underscores.

### EDIT 2

For clarity, the *`before`* and *`after`* words don't have any special meaning at all in PHP. They are purely used as descriptive words, as I stated previously, and as example, a hook called `before_something` is in al probablity used **before** a function/another hook called `something`. It is as easy as that

Answer (score 0):

[`ws_plugin__s2member_pro_before_sc_authnet_form_after_shortcode_atts`](http://www.s2member.com/codex/stable/source/pro/s2member-pro/includes/classes/gateways/authnet/authnet-form-in.inc.php/#src_doc_line_89) is [`do_action()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_action) function and this one display position of function execution.

U have need change argument before `sc_authnet_form` and After `shortcode_atts` in filter function.